# Can't find function after adding iFrame

Tags: javascript

A simple Hello world function and a button that illustrate the error. Comment out the iFrame - works like a charm. Remove the comments - Fatal error. I am puzzled.

Source:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
    <body>
  <button onclick="helloWorld()">Click me</button>

 <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com"/> 
</body>
</html>
<script>
    function helloWorld() {
        console.log("Hello world");
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why is the script element placed there? Move it inside `<body>`.

Comment: Move your function in side the head part of HTML

Comment: Use the correct `iframe` syntax. `<iframe></iframe>`

Comment: It is not a requirement; I just personally prefer to have the script 'torn' from the Html and css. Edit: Yeah, like Broken Heart said, I've been using a wrong iFrame element.

Comment: With "jsfiddle" it's work perfectly  - Try : http://jsfiddle.net/DCRZr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put your **javascript** correctly :

```
<head>
   <meta charset="utf-8" />
   <script>
      function helloWorld() {
         console.log("Hello world");
      }
   </script>
</head>
```

Retype the `<iframe>` to right syntax.

```
<iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
        src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com">
</iframe>
```

**Full Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script>
        function helloWorld() {
            alert("Hello world");
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="helloWorld()">Click me</button>

    <iframe id="ytplayer" type="text/html" width="640" height="390"
            src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/M7lc1UVf-VE?autoplay=1&origin=http://example.com">
    </iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

It should works.